# What threat model does disable_functions assume in PHP?

Tags: php, security, rce

`disable_functions` allows to disable certain functions in PHP that are deemed "dangerous". However, I’m finding it difficult to grasp what kind of threat model such a feature assumes.

If you disable certain functions to protect against your own application code, then this is at best a duct-tape solution to monkey-patch a poorly written codebase.

If, on the other hand, you’re using `disable_functions` to limit the extent of an RCE attack, then this is a pointless endeavour because in a lot of cases your data can be exfiltrated using "simple" functions not present in this blacklist.

It seems to me that defining such a blacklist only provides a false sense of security. If an RCE attack is successful, then your execution context is already breached and blacklisting certain functions feels like a losing battle.

Are there any real security benefits to `disable_functions` that I’m missing?

Comment: Disabling the most broken pieces of the the language so that the FNG doesn't use them.

Comment: What does FNG stand for?

Comment: F***ing new guy.

Comment: This is a very old feature. I suspect it was written with shared hosting in mind, but I don't think it offers a substantial benefit in 2023.

Comment: It's a tool that a sysadmin can use to limit functions on a server that are most frequently used in exploits without having to know anything about the applications.   Web security has no panacea.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question because it's not a practical programming problem. You might do better to browse the pages of [security.se], and possibly ask this question there. Check their [help centre](https://security.stackexchange.com/help) before you post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here are possible use cases:

1. Configuration of shared hosting to protect against the execution of arbitrary operating system commands, manipulation of file paths, etc. Example: `exec, shell_exec, passthru, popen, link`. Or temporary blocking, for example, of the `mail` function, when its use violated the permitted behavior algorithms.
2. To simplify code control in organizations, when it is easier to prohibit the use of functions instead of monitoring them (or writing automatic rules for this), and then spend time rewriting them in the code.
3. To satisfy some security compliance (PCI DSS, SOX, HIPAA, ...). Where the more arguments in favor of your security you have, the easier it is to get the desired status.
4. Perhaps someone likes to prohibit themselves from using something. Freedom in all its forms, you know ;)

Comment: Regarding 1), is it still an issue for shared hosting nowadays which uses containers, LVE or some other form of virtualization? disable_functions seems like a tool for shared hosting installations from the 2000s.

Comment: I don’t argue, but shared hosting is a separate world of earnings, and I wouldn’t be surprised if there are quite a few of them who haven’t changed since the 2000s